# Unable to execute "custom script extension" on Azure VM using azure CLI from linux sub system

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-cli, pester, azure-vm-templates

I am working on developing post-deployment Pester validation script for my project. I need to push pester scripts into the VM as custom script extension using Azure CLI.

Following is the command I executed:

```
az vm extension set --resource-group SomeRG--vm-name SimpleVM --name 
customScript --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --settings '{"fileUris": 
["https://github.com/myname/DSCConfig/blob/master/pester.ps1"], 
"commandToExecute":"powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 
pester.ps1"}'  --version 2.0
```

and I got the below error in the Linux interface after executing above command:

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
>   8ba16fc0-fea6-4650-bb0a-2b73c9613dfe. Handler
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.customScript' has reported failure for VM
>   Extension 'customScript' with terminal error code '1007' and error
>   message: 'Install failed for the plugin (name:
>   Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.customScript, version 2.0.6) with exception
>   The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS
>   platform.'

And while checking the extension on VM saw the status as "Transitioning " and details as Install failed for the plugin (name: Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.customScript, version 2.0.6) with exception The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform)

Alternatively I tried with other publishers: Microsoft.Compute and Microsoft.OSTCExtensions

Unfortunately, none of them worked. I have been stuck at this step for past two days. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error seems to suggest that your target VM is not a Windows machine, but rather some other OS where Windows PowerShell is not supported. If this is the case there is now PowerShell Core that is cross-platform but I don't personally know if you can use it via custom script extensions yet.

Comment: Thanks for your input Mark. But the VM I am trying to access is a simple VM configured on windows OS.  I have used Microsoft.Azure.Extensions which is throwing the error " 'Install failed for the plugin (name: Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.customScript, version 2.0.6) with exception The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be using the wrong custom script extension (the one you are using I believe is for Linux VMs). I think you should be using the one named "CustomScriptExtension" with a publisher of "Microsoft.Compute" and version set to "1.9" as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows).

Specifically, try this command instead:

```
az vm extension set --resource-group SomeRG--vm-name SimpleVM --name CustomScriptExtension --publisher Microsoft.Compute --settings '{"fileUris": ["https://github.com/myname/DSCConfig/blob/master/pester.ps1"], "commandToExecute":"powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File pester.ps1"}' --version 1.9
```

Comment: Awesome, I got the fix for the error now. As you rightly mentioned I tried publisher  as micosoft.compute with name as CustomScriptExtension and it worked like  a charm. Thankslot.